# Should I put codeigniter model object to globals

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was just wondering if somebody could share an advice.
I am building large Codeigniter application, and I'm thinking about putting some model objects  into `$GLOBALS`.

This way I could do something like `global $post;` or `global $wpdb` in Wordpress.

Does this make sense and is it a good idea? Should I, in such case, autoload these models first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea to pollute global namespace while using singleton pattern. When you're not in the CodeIgniter super-object simply use `$CI =& get_instance();`

Why would you want to do that anyway? What is the reason you want that? To write less by omitting `this->`? It's not the case then, as you will have to write `global $post` in each of the files and functions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I find it useful.
How about autoloading models?

Comment: What about that? That is a completely normal and common practice, load as many as you want, but tend to load only the ones that are needed for every single page of your project as you can't make them not load for any single page.

Comment: I was thinking of autoloading models such as User, and Article. Thanks for reply

Comment: User model is something I would put to autoload too, but the article model, even on a dedicated blog, is something you should examine as even on a blog you have some pages like "About me", "Contact" and some other

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the whole idea of object oriented coding...
If you want to reuse objects use a dependency injection container.

Putting anything into the global namespace in OO code is just plain wrong.